# Print 2D array in txt file saves only last row - incorrect use of .join?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a 2D array (yieldpergroup) and trying to save vertically each array with something like

```
with open('txt/All_numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    lines = ['  \t'.join([str(x[i]) for x in yieldpergroup]) for i in range(0,len(max(yieldpergroup)))]
```

i.e. my array is something like that

```
yieldpergroup([a,b,c,d][1,2,3,4][!,@,#,$])
```

and I want to have it in the format

```
 a 1 !
 b 2 @
 c 3 #
 d 4 $
```

However, the txt although correctly includes all the columns, however only the last one is shown  correctly, all other columns are filled with zeroes (like when I first initialized with yieldpergroup = [[0 for i in range(cols)] for j in range(rows)]). What am I doing wrong while using join ?

Comment: There is no `D` in the `yieldgroup` array so how you are supposed to get it included in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `zip` transposition pattern to get the desired result. Use:

```
yieldpergroup = (['A','B','C', 'D'], [1,2,3,4], ['!','@','#','$'])

with open('txt/All_numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    for t in zip(*yieldpergroup):
        f.write("\t".join(map(str, t)) + "\n")
```

After executing the above code your `.txt` file should look like:

```
A 1 !
B 2 @
C 3 #
D 4 $
```

Comment: @ShunhamSharma 

`f.write(f"{x} {y} {z}\n")

                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @Terma That's because you are using python version below 3.6 so instead use `f.write("{} {} {}\n".format(x, y, z))`

Comment: thanks, seems to working - howt that should be modified if instead of 3, I have N arrays ? (ie more than x,y,z)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something likes this:

```
with open('All_numbers.txt', 'a') as f:
   f.write("\n".join(["\t".join([group[index] for group in yieldpergroup]) for index, entry in enumerate(range(0,len(max(yieldpergroup))))]))
```

But if you want to be able to comprehend your code again in a couple of days, there's also no shame in this:

```
with open('All_numbers.txt', 'a') as f:
    row = ""
    rows = []
    biggest_group = range(0,len(max(yieldpergroup)))
    for index, entry in enumerate(biggest_group):
        for group in yieldpergroup:
            row += f"{group[index]}\t"
        rows.append(row)
        row = ""
    f.write("\n".join(rows))
```

You probably also want to account for the case if your groups don't share an equal length, since you are already checking for the list with the most entries, which would make the list comprehension even harder to read.

Comment: @pic for the second solution

`row += f"{group[index]}\t"
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`  

I am using python 2.7

Comment: Try `row += group[index] + "\t"`.

Comment: @pic for the first solution : this results exactly like what I was getting in the first place, ie, all zeros except last column which is filled in properly -

Comment: Could you provide the exact code of how you initialize the yieldgroup array?